# How to store a class if it could be one of several types?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, unity-game-engine

I have a design issue with a project of mine.

I have 3 classes: `Planet`, `Star`, `Ship`. These classes are attached to a corresponding prefab and contain data such as Name, position, size, etc. `Planet` prefab has `Planet` class attached, not the others. `Star` prefab has `Star` class and `Ship` prefab has `Ship` class attached.

There is also a class called `SelectObject` and it handles selection functions (when user clicks on a prefab). Basically it displays in a little window image of the selected object and some data pulled from the corresponding class that is attached to the prefab. This class is attached to all clickable/selectable objects: `Planet`, `Star` and `Ship`.

Now, I am trying to make it smart and trying to use generics so that SelectObject can handle ANY current and future classes. When I only had Planet object as a selectable object, I declared:

```
public Planet planet;
```

and if a planet is selected, assign the data to this var and then use this var to populate info on the mini window.
But now I have 3 classes and I do not want to 'hardcode' and create new variables for each addition class. I want to use a single variable that can be ANY one of 3 (and potentially more in the future) classes.

At first I thought I'd declare `public System.Object myObject;` and using generics to assign whatever comes in to it:

```
public System.Object myObject;
public T Set<T>(T param)
{
    myObject = param;
    return param;
}
```

This works one way - no problems assigning to an Object, but then retrieving it back to Planet I get `InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type`.

So, is having 3 variables for a class and have an overloaded method to return a non-null one the only way to go with? or is there some fancy way of doing this?

PS: After some research I found `dynamic` keyword for .NET 4.0, which I think would solve the issue i am having. But it seems that Unity does not support 4.0?

Thanks for any insight.

**EDIT 1:**
To clarify what currently is happening in my project. I have 3 prefabs: Ship, Star, Planet. Each prefab has SelectObject class attached to it. Each prefab also has a corresponding data class attached to it wrapped in a prefab class. SO at the end, each prefab has 2 classes attached to it. Another script loads a data file with planets/ships/stars data, instantiates corresponding prefabs and populate corresponding data class within the prefab.

SelectObject has `OnMouseDown` function and it is supposed to extract the data class from the GameObject when user clicks on one of the instantiated prefabs. This is when I am experiencing issues: `((Prefab)(selObj.GetComponent(typeof(Prefab)))).myObject` myObject is of `System.Object` type and supposed to contain either a class of type Ship, Planet or Star. But, when I try to convert back from Object to whatever class it is supposed to be, I get the above mentioned error message.

Further to add to confusion: If I have a simple test script such as this:

```
public string myObjectType;
public System.Object myObject;
```

...

```
Planet myPlanet = new Planet();
myPlanet.Name = "whatever";
myPlanet.Size = "BIG";
myObject = myPlanet;
```

...

When at a later point I try to extract `Planet` class from the `Object`, it works `((Planet)myObject).Name`. But, when I have the more complicated way when I extract `Object` from `GameObject` it fails... I don't know why.

**EDIT 2:**

I found why my initial conversion from `System.Object` back to corresponding type failed. It appears `System.Object` variable loses its type when I instantiate GameObject. It's weird, because another variable of type `Planet` is fine. I will investigate further, but so far it looks like if I instantiate a GameObject that has a class attached to it and that class has a System.Object variable and you assign something to it, that something is lost during instantiation process.

So, a quick hack to fix the issue is: when loading data and instantiating prefabs, after calling `Instantiate` function to physically create a GameObject, assign the System.Object variable again. Here is pieace of code:

```
// this is where I create a GameObject. Its not instantiated yet. System.Object variable inside newPlanet3 is assigned and correct
GameObject newPlanet3 = CreateStellarObject(myPlanet);
// this piece actually instantiates the object and places in the proper position
GameObject newPlanet2 = Instantiate(newPlanet3, myPlanet.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
// this is the fix. After instantiate, System.Object variable inside newPlanet2 is lost. Need to reassign it.
((Prefab)(newPlanet2.GetComponent(typeof(Prefab)))).myObject = ((Prefab)(newPlanet3.GetComponent(typeof(Prefab)))).myObject;
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I do not need to reassign other variables after instantiating.

Comment: Usually this solved with implementing common interface on all classes or inheritance + virtual methods, not sure if you can get very far with C# generics.

Comment: I agree with Alexei. From the description, it seems that inheritance is a better fit than generics. If you think that would not work in your case, you should be more explicit as to why and what led you to generics as an alternative.

Comment: Problem is that those object may have a lot of unrelated/uneeded fields. And the question remains: is there a way to handle a dynamic class type? Basically, here is a class of type Planet or Ship or Star, show me corresponding data from corresponding class (Planet may have name, ship may have speed, star may have brightness)... etc.

Comment: You can use custom attributes to mark properties that should be discoverable by the `SelectObject`, then you can use Reflection to get the marked properties and their values. If all properties are to be discoverable by the `SelectObject`, there is obviously no need to have custom attributes on all of them, and simply reflect on all properties.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Do you have a simple example? I do not have much experience with reflection.

Comment: Google is the alternative to experience here. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET

Comment: By the way, you can also check `bool b = myObj is MyType` or use `MyType x = myObj as MyType` (and check for null) to avoid `InvalidCastException`, in case you don't want to go with reflection.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Trying to convert to a wrong class is not a problem. I  know the class is of type Planet, and im trying to convert from Object to Planet but it fails. Somehow the object is of different type. Even though when I assign to it, my log shows its of correct type.

Comment: When you debug, the watch window will show you it's actual type. If you cast `MyObj` to `Object` and back to `MyObj`, you don't get an `InvalidCastException`. Make sure your code does what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

[Please check this solution.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FhzJxA)
I have created abstract base class that uses reflection to get/set fields or properties.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;    

public abstract class B
{
    private Type _type;

    protected B()
    {
        _type = GetType();
    }

    public object Get(string name)
    {

        object data = null;

        var field = _type.GetField(name);
        if(field != null)
        {
            data = field.GetValue(this);
        }
        else
        {
            var member = _type.GetProperty(name);
            if(member != null)
            {
                data = member.GetValue(this);
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string name)
    {
        var data = Get(name);

        if(data != null && data is T)
            return (T)data;

        return default(T);
    }

    public void Set<T>(string name, T data)
    {
        var field = _type.GetField(name);
        if(field != null)
        {
            field.SetValue(this, data);
        }
        else
        {
            var member = _type.GetProperty(name);
            if(member != null)
            {
                member.SetValue(this, data);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class B1 : B
{
    public int Info1 {get; set;}
}

public class B2 : B
{
    public string Info2;
}

public class C
{
    public object mObject;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b1 = new B1();
        var b2 = new B2();
        b1.Info1 = 1;
        b2.Info2 = "sad";

        Console.WriteLine(b1.Get<int>("Info1"));
        Console.WriteLine(b2.Get("Info2"));

        Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\n");

        var c  = new C();
        c.mObject = new B1();
        (c.mObject as B).Set("Info1", 123);
        Console.WriteLine((c.mObject as B).Get("Info1"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a common interface that simply gives your objects a type that you want. That is, the type will allow you to group them and handle them without caring what is what.

Example:

```
 public interface DragableObject
 {
     void DragMe();
 }

 public class Star : MonoBehaviour, DragableObject
 {
     public void DragMe()
     {
         print("I am a Star, I don't move easily.");
     }
 }

 public class Ship : MonoBehaviour, DragableObject
 {
     public void DragMe()
     {
         print("Engaging warp speed.");
     }
 }
```

Have a class that maintains these objects.

```
public class GameManager
{
     private DragableObject [] list;
}
```

Then you can simply call `DragMe()` and each object should worry about how they handle that.

```
list[0].DragMe();
```

Comment: I don't think this approach will work for me since you move the action from the function class to the data class. In my case, the data case has data. The function class draws GUI elements and then displays it. Also, I failed to mention it, I am not passing the data class, I extract it from the GameObject I pass to SelectObject class. I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: Also, please explain what your data class is. It almost sounds like you  have a container for data and you are passing it around (not a good idea).